# jQuery UI.Layout only resize west pane issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the JQuery [UI.Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) plugin to create a software layout for a very complex UI. I have stripped it down to the most basic 5 pane layout and all panes collapse and reopen. However I need the east pane to be re-sizable, I looked through the documentation (very long, but not very useful) to find the solution, but I didn't find it. If anyone has any experience with this frustrating plug in then I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

I am using this example http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/example.html and have tried everything mentioned in the docs, I would also like a button to close the west pane, but yet again everything that I have tried does not work.

Comment: For anyone else tearing their hair out trying to figure out this plugin, this worked for me, but you also have to include JQuery UI Draggable.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 outerLayout = $('body').layout({
  center__paneSelector: ".ui-layout-outer"
         , west__size: 250
      , east__size: 250
      , south__size: 60
   ,east__slidable:  true
   ,east__resizable:  true
   ,west__slidable:  false
   ,west__resizable:  false
   ,south__slidable:  false
   ,south__resizable:  false
});
 innerLayout = $('div.ui-layout-outer').layout({
   center__paneSelector: ".ui-layout-center"
            ,north__paneSelector: ".ui-layout-north"
            ,north__size: 100
   ,north__slidable:  false
   ,north__resizable:  false
 });
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set east to be resizable.

```
outerLayout = $('body').layout({
    default : {
        //All pane properties defaults
    },
    //East only
    east : {
       resizable : true
    }
});
```

EDIT:  Just viewed your link, and you need jQuery UI plugins...either link the jQuery UI plugins you need, or just add jQuery UI in your project.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have solved the issue but in a far more convoluted fashion.

Comment: Yes, the plugin can be a little confusing at first and I feel that the author of the plugin's way of doing the examples makes it way more difficult than it should be

Comment: Too true jyore, but cant find anything similar that is better documented or built